# Sites page Office 365

Tags: office-365, mysites

Is there a way to modifiy this page (Sites in Office 365 that shows you the sites you are following, the suggested sites and the promoted sites)?

I can't see an option like Edit page or something like that for this page

Comment: Hi, which do wish to edit?

Comment: Followed sites? the sites page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, what you wanted is to manage the promoted sites and sites you are following.

For promoted sites, only administrators can manage it. It is global to all users. In the administrator view, you will find the boxes(sites) to be editable.

For sites you are following, you can un-follow sites by clicking on Stop Following button or go to the site and click Unfollow (located on the upper right corner of the site). Similarly, for sites that you want to follow, simply navigate to the site and click Follow.

This [link](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Promote-sites-on-the-Sites-page-be0c9245-f465-4c3b-96ff-8046bd551bf3) will give you a more detailed guide for managing promoted links. On the other hand, this [link](https://support.office.com/en-CA/article/Video-Follow-a-SharePoint-site-33db6fa5-9528-45d7-bcc7-f9c1faaacae0) demonstrates on how to follow or stop following sites. I believe there is no way wherein you can manage the sites in a tabular (like a list) manner.

Comment: What I really want is try to change that page, to customize that page: ../Social/Sites.aspx